# WebRTC gathering candidate gives different results in same browser(chrome)

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, ice

I'm new to WebRTC and there is something odd about gathering ICE candidates for WebRTC.

As in this picture, gathering ICE candidates from [this page](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) gave me a normal list of candidates.

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jinHk.png)

However, when I download the code of this page in local, a completely different result is obtained as shown in this figure.

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhDB3.png)

Also, when collecting ice candidates through function execution in console tab of each page, different results return.

Where does this difference come from?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The likely difference is that at some point in time you have allowed camera access on webrtc.github.io. This lets webrtc gather more candidates than just the default network route.

If you check "acquire camera/microphone permissions" you should see more candidates locally too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I was able to get only the address in the form of "[random string].local" even if I checked "acquire camera/microphone permissions".

Comment: From what I've investigated, it's called "mDNS", but I don't know why it only appears in this format in the local environment.

Comment: are you trying from a file:// url? That is a special case

Comment: Yes. It's just open "index.html" file. Does the browser behave differently depending on whether the page is a local file or content from server?